# iOS Keyboard Dismiss Interactively - Get frame as user is pulling down

Tags: ios, keyboard

I'm drawing a blank on how to get the keyboard frame as you drag it off the screen. I know how to get once the animation starts or ends using `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`, `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification`, `UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification` but I'm looking for the constant update as you drag it off the screen. For example, I'd like to know where the keyboard's frame is at this point of drag
[image: Looking for keyboard frame when I'm dragging]

I'm trying to use the keyboard frame to adjust the tableview that should be right up against the keyboard as you drag down.